# Is is possible to migrate a client from a disconnected VM host?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

One of our VM hosts (5.0) got disconnected. All of our Clients are on Shared Datastore.

Is it possible to migrate the clients on the disconnected host (Vcenter Essentials) to a connected host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. VCenter Essentials isn't a VM host.
2. If the VM's that were being hosted were on shared stotage then you should be able to add those VM's to another host by browsing the shared storage from another host, finding the folders for those VM's, right-clicking the vmx file for each VM, and selecting "Add to Inventory". That will add those VM's to that host and allow you to start them.
3. If and when you get the disconnected host back online it's still going to think that it owns those VM's. You should right-click those VM's and select "Remove from Inventory".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply browse the datastore and add the guest VM to inventory since vCenter still thinks it is attached to the old host. Following the steps in https://communities.vmware.com/message/2410612#2410612, I was able to migrate the guest via the following:

1. ssh to the target host
2. Adapt this command to your path: `vim-cmd solo/registervm /vmfs/volumes/YourDisk/YourHost/something.vmx`
3. Go to vCenter and start the guest VM
4. When vCenter asks if you moved or copied the VM, answer: I moved it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "clone" my VMs from a failed ESX host (hardware failure and was completely offline) by copying the directory of each VM I wanted to recover in the datastore in to a new folder. Then I had to download and modify the .vmx file for the VM to change the display name setting to something new (needs to be unique), delete the network adapter settings (duplicate MAC errors), and delete all UUID settings (think there were three in my case). Once all that is done re-upload the .vmx over the top of the old one in the new folder and then register the VM on the new host from the datastore. After that re-add your network adapters to match what you previously had and start the VM up.